# Client-server time synchronisation for latency testing (Sockets)

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp, latency

I want to measure the latency for a simple program using UDP then TCP. I am currently using time.time() from time library at both ends and I compare them (time stamp before sending at the server and time after recieving at the client). The server would send its time stamp and the reciever will compare the time to calculate latency.
This worked fine when using 127.0.0.1 loopback address. Since its on the same machine, time reference is the same.
if I implement this on my actual application where the server and client are seperate, I can't get the accurate latency since there is a time difference between the two machine.

Is there a way to synchronize time for better latency calcultaion?

Also, how do I maintain low UDP latency all the time when I have high data rate and moderate processing fter receiving? and will the client's distance affect latency?

Thank you